# Insert missing dates for each course

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
row  courseid  date           V1          V2
456     5031 2011-07-15       50           1
457     5031 2011-07-16       50           1
458     5031 2011-07-18        0           0
459     5031 2011-07-19        0           0
460     5031 2011-07-20        0           0
461     5031 2011-07-21        0           0
485     5052 2011-06-30        0           0
486     5052 2011-07-01        0           0
487     5052 2011-07-02        0           0
488     5052 2011-07-03        0           0
```

For each courseid value, I need to use rle() on V2, however, that only makes sense if the dates for each courseid are continuous. But in the above example, you will see, that for courseid=5031, the date 2011-07-17 is missing. How do I insert missing dates in the dataset above, with V1=0 and V2=0, for each courseid?

I figured out that I can find the first and last date for each courseid with the following code:

```
c <- unique(t$courseid)
test <- sapply (c, function (y) {
  return (range(t$date[t$courseid==y]))
})
c2 <- as.data.frame(cbind (c,test[1,],test[2,]))
names(c2) = c("courseid","first","last")
```

So, my idea was to convert c2 to a (courseid,date) matrix, with all the dates between first and last for each courseid, and then use merge. Does anybody know how to do that, or know another method?

Comment: Your idea of merging is good. Create a dataframe using: `seq(as.Date("1990/1/1"), as.Date("1999/1/1"), "years")` and then use the `merge` function. Good luck.

Comment: This question was correctly identified as a duplicate. My solution was:

    do.call(rbind,
            by(
              t,
              t$courseid,
              function(x) {
                out <- merge(
                  data.frame(
                    courseid=x$course[1],
                    date=seq.int(min(x$date),max(x$date),by=1)
                  ),
                  x,
                  all.x=TRUE
                )
                out$drugpresent[is.na(out$drugpresent)] <- 0
                out
              }  
            )
    )